# Difference between clean & build and build?

Tags: java, netbeans

My understanding of build is that it compiles only the Java files which has been edited from last build and clean build will delete all the class files and compile all the files again. So what is the utility of clean build when build alone can suffice the need of giving me the latest version of class files?

Comment: What if you have removed some classes ? ) Clean will ensure that removed or renamed classes are not longer on the classpath.

Comment: I had a test failure caused by @Babl's exact scenario this week; there was an old test class still hanging around that no longer matched the updated code. `mvn clean test` fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes there are processes that update the class files or other dependencies that may not be tracked by the build system.  Other times, a local change outside the build system (e.g. vi or notepad) that isn't tracked.

In either case, it's useful to do a full build before a final checkin or raising an issue.